# ajax is duplicating my div

Tags: jquery, ajax

The Ajax function of jQuery is working properly, but the return of the data being inserted into the div **`<# exibeCep>`** being duplicated when the User clicks the button several times.
I tried using `remove()`, `e.preventDefault()`, `StopPropagation()`, `bind()` and others but nothing prevented the duplication of the `div`.
What did I post to avoid duplicating the div?

HTML:

```
<div id="exibeCep" class="conf_frete">
  <h1>Escolha a opção do frete</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#buscafrete').click(function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  cep = $('#cep').val();
  $.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : "{% url 'get_frete' %}",
    dataType: "json",
    data    : {
      data               : cep,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
    },
    success : function (retorno) {

      if (retorno['sedex_cod_error'] == -3 || retorno['pac_cod_error'] == -3) {
        $('<label><input type="radio" name="zipcode" id=' + 'sedex' + ' value=' + 'CEP de destino invalido' + '/>' + 'CEP de destino invalido.' + '</label>').appendTo('#exibeCep');
      } else {
        $('<label><input type="radio" name="zipcode" checked id=' + 'sedex' + ' value=' + retorno['Sedex'] + '/>' + retorno['Sedex'] + ' ( ' + 'Sedex' + ' ) ' + '</label>').appendTo('#exibeCep');
        $('<label><input type="radio" name="zipcode" id=' + 'sedex' + ' value=' + retorno['Pac'] + '/>' + retorno['Pac'] + ' ( ' + 'Pac' + ' ) ' + '</label>').appendTo('#exibeCep');
      }
    },
    error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //alert("FALHOU");
      console.log('Error');
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    },
  });

});
```

Comment: you aren't doing anything to clear the div before you add more stuff to it, therefore each click will add additional content to what was there previously.

Comment: how do I clear the div before?

Comment: use `$(targetelement).html(thehtmltoinsert)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid double clicks from the user I normally add a class, for example `is-loading`, and then check for that class.  If it exists do nothing and return.  Then in `success` I remove the class.

**Example**

```
$('#buscafrete').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('is-loading')) {
        // Do nothing.
        return;
    }

    $(this).addClass('is-loading');

    $.ajax({
    },
    success: function(retorno){
        $(this).removeClass('is-loading');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried as you suggested but I get error: 
TypeError: this.hasClass is not a function 
I'm new to jquery. 
thank you

Comment: @Ricardo Sorry typo, missed the `$` on `this`.  Have updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not solution of your problem but this can be helpful to you. What you can do is handle ajaxstart and ajaxstop method and in those you can enable and disable button so that ultimately you are restricting user to click inbetween...So user can not click and your data will not ne redundant...